# displaying map of a map in visualforce(and using inner key as url path of outer key)

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

Hi I've been trying to figure this out on my own but haven't been able to get it to work. I have a map of a map `Map<string,Map<String, list<Accounts>>> mapToAccounts` . The inner key is a string which represents an **url** while the outer key is just the name of the site. I am attempting to create a hyperlink which shows the name of the site and the destination is the inner key(which is an url). Something like this `<apex:outputLink value="{!theAccountsOfSitesAndMaps[innerkey]}">{!outerKey}</apex:outputLink>` . Any suggestions will be great.

```
public Map<String,Map<String, list<Accounts>>> getTheAccountsOfSitesAndMaps() {         
    return maptoaccounts;
    }
```

Just updated below with suggestions from sfdcfox and Eric but receiving a new error: **Error is in expression '{!TheAccountsOfSitesAndMaps[outerKey][innerKey]}' in component  in page**

```
 <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:repeat value="{!TheAccountsOfSitesAndMaps}" var="outerKey">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!TheAccountsOfSitesAndMaps}[outerKey]" var="innerKey">        
          <apex:repeat value="{!TheAccountsOfSitesAndMaps[outerKey][innerKey]}" var="account">
              <apex:column headervalue="Sites" />   
          <apex:outputLink value="{!innerKey}">{!outerKey}</apex:outputLink>            

          </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Is it important in your example markup that you've got two maps one called `TheAccountsOfSitesAndMaps` and one called `mapToAccounts`? Do you really have two separate map instances?

Comment: Hi Mark, I apologize for not providing enough information. I'am actually returning the map in a method called TheAccountsOfSitesAndMaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<apex:repeat value="{!mapToAccounts}" var="outerKey">
    <apex:repeat value="{!mapToAccounts[outerKey]}" var="innerKey">
        <apex:repeat value="{!mapToAccounts[outerKey][innerKey]}" var="account">
            <apex:outputLink value="{!innerKey}">
                {!outerKey}
            </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Of course, feel free to use tables (apex:dataTable, apex:pageBlockTable, etc) as appropriate, and any other dressing you need.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Your answer works with apex repeat but I'm having troubles getting it to work with apex pageblocktable. Could you offer any help?

Comment: There is no difference between an `<apex:repeat />` and an `<apex:pageBlockTable />` aside from the fact that one renders anything you wish to build with it and the other renders an HTML table with the Salesforce pageblock table style and structure. Can you demonstrate a specific problem with the `<apex:pageBlockTable />` that was working well with the `<apex:repeat />` tag?

Comment: @sw6-KTBFFH Within a pageBlockTable, all elements must be contained in a `apex:column` element in order to be displayed. Other than that, there is no functional difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Seems the repeat does not work well inside a pageblock table.

This however does work:

CLASS

```
    public class vfpagetest{

public Map<String,Map<String,String>> tmp {get;set;}
public String s {get;set;}

    public vfpagetest(){
    s = 'TEST';
        tmp = New Map<String,Map<String,String>>();

        tmp.put('1',New Map<String,String>{'A'=>'3','B'=>'4'});
        tmp.put('2',New Map<String,String>{'C'=>'5','D'=>'6'});
    system.debug(logginglevel.error,tmp);
    }


}
```

VF PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="vfpagetest">

<apex:pageBlock >

<table>
    <th>test</th>

    <apex:repeat value="{!tmp}" var="outerKey">
    <tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!tmp[outerKey]}" var="innerKey">
    <td>{!outerKey} - {!innerKey}</td>
    <td>{!tmp[outerKey][innerKey]}</td>
    </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
   </table>


</apex:pageBlock>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Eric I apologize if it seems I have not been responding or giving any feedback- I'm in the process of moving to a new house and been running around all day. Like you may have seen yourself the apex repeat does not work entirely well inside the pageblocktable. I will implement your new solution as soon as I get a bit of work time. Thank you.

Comment: No worries at all. Just trying to help. Hopefully SFDCFOX will chime in here and help with a more elegant solution. I did not have time to work anything but this mock up up.